# int object has no attribute replace when trying to run a CQL command in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have  a counter column family in cassandra. When i try to view the data from CQL i get an error even though there is data in the column family.

```
SELECT * from userstats;
```

Generates the following error:

'int' object has no attribute 'replace'

I can confirm that the data is in the column family and is working properly since I can view the data with the Datastax Opscenter data explorer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're using an older version of cqlsh. Upgrading it (just copying the `bin/cqlsh` file from the Cassandra 1.1 branch head, along with everything under the `pylib` directory, into place) ought to solve this.

If it doesn't, running cqlsh with `--debug` would help a lot in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: root@datasrv01:~/apache-cassandra-1.1.0/pylib# cqlsh
Connection error: Invalid method name: 'set_cql_version'
root@datasrv01:~/apache-cassandra-1.1.0/pylib# cqlsh --debug
Using CQL driver: <module 'cql' from '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/cql/__init__.pyc'>
Using thrift lib: <module 'thrift' from '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/thrift/__init__.pyc'>
Connection error: Invalid method name: 'set_cql_version'
root@datasrv01:~/apache-cassandra-1.1.0/pylib# cqlsh
Connection error: Invalid method name: 'set_cql_version'

Comment: You should copy the files into their places in the Cassandra tree, or else copy the `lib/*.zip` libraries along with the cqlsh ones. Cqlsh looks for the python-cql library in `../lib/cql-internal-only-*.zip`, and since in your case it didn't find it, it fell back on your locally installed python-cql library, which is out of date.